# nginx under high traffic: network goes down when log writes to disk?

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, performance, configuration

An VPS with 2 vCPUs, with Ubuntu 20.04 and nginx.

Nothing changed regarding to loging: neither on nginx, rsyslogd, or journald.

I launch ab (apache-benchmark) from a nearby VPS, like this:

```
ab -k -c 300 -n 3000000 'https://example.com'
```

Then, in the provider graphs, I can see how the **network goes down** (throughput and packets per second) **while the disk write increases**. This happens at intervals of **each 30 seconds**.

The disk writes increase in throughput, but the disk iops stay low, 1 or 2 IOPS during all the benchmark, there is nothing else in the system, but my SSH in the internal interface, with a tail -f of the nginx logs.

So I suspect maybe it's the way that nginx is writing the log to disk, or, maybe the default sysctl, and the way the **kernel is syncing** the changes to disk (?)

I don't see too many sysctl settings at 30 seconds:

```
# sysctl -a | grep '30$'
kernel.acct = 4 2       30
net.core.xfrm_acq_expires = 30
net.ipv4.ipfrag_time = 30
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv6.route.gc_interval = 30
vm.max_map_count = 65530
```

But there is this at 3000 centisecs:

```
# sysctl -a | grep '3000$'
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
```

Could be that one?

> dirty_expire_centisecs
> This tunable is used to define when dirty data is old enough to be eligible
> for writeout by the kernel flusher threads.  It is expressed in 100'ths
> of a second.  Data which has been dirty in-memory for longer than this
> interval will be written out next time a flusher thread wakes up.

What I'm worried, is about the traffic going from 7K pps to zero each 30s, and coming back when the disk write is done.

What **can be done** to avoid that behavior?

Here is an image of the graphs, that shows the issue as described: [VPS performance graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IBmU.png)

**Edit:** sysctl findings

**Update**

It's not related to the nginx log.

By the @berndbausch indications, did look at the client side, and there are the same graphs of the network going down.

Repeating the bench with:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined buffer=64K flush=5s;
```

And:

```
sysctl -w vm.dirty_expire_centisecs=500
```

The disk IOPs increase to from 1 to +/- 10, the disk througput graph makes peaks each 5 seconds, **but** the network graphs still do the same "down to 0" in 30 seconds intervals, both in the server and the client.

More interseting, repetaing the benchmark with:

```
access_log off;
```

The disk graphs stay at 0, but the network graphs do the same.

In this image, both benchmarks can be seen as described, let side with flush each 5s, and right side with no access log:

[image]

**Update 2**

Performing iperf dual test on port 443... the server graph is plain at 1 Gbps, but, the iperf client has te same behavior, network out graphs go down to 0 each 30 seconds.

Will try with a different client, or tune a litle bit the client OS, limits and sysctl, let's see.

**Update 3**

This looks like a monitoring bug in the control panel.

Did repeat the benchmarks from other VPS as client, and from a dedicated server (bare metal), always the same graphs...

But, if I launch bmon in both sides during the tests... it looks plain:

[image]

The same in the receiver than in the sender. 10 Gbps between two VPS and 1 Gbps from the dedicated server to the VPS. Always plain with 1 second resolution.

So... mistery solved.

Comment: My remarks/questions: (1) How is network in/out measured? (2) I don't see such a great correlation of disk IO and network out and (3) no correlation with CPU utilization. However, (4) network in and network out are correlated. If network in/out is measured at the NIC (and even if it is measured elsewhere), I would wonder if the problem is on the `ab` side. I.e. the VPS that runs `ab` could have problems breathing every 30 seconds.

Comment: mmm (1) no agents in the server, so I suppose the meassures are external (in the host, not the guest). (2) looking the posted image, I see the 3 graphs (disk throughput, network traffic, network pps) change at the same time. (3) Indeed, CPU stays on the same levels (4) didn't think about that side, will repeat the benchmarks today looking at the client graphs/logs/stats, thanks!

Comment: It is possible that you are triggering some traffic shaping (DDoS protection) at your provider network level due to high PPS.

Comment: So, @berndbausch did nail it in (1), this seems like a monitoring bug. If you suggest it as a response I will accept it. I will make an "Update 3" with the related information to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my remarks/questions are the answer:

(1) How is network in/out measured?

(2) I don't see such a great correlation of disk IO and network out and 
(3) no correlation with CPU utilization. However,

(4) network in and network out are correlated.

If network in/out is measured at the NIC (and even if it is measured elsewhere), I would wonder if the problem is on the `ab` side. I.e. the VPS that runs `ab` could have problems breathing every 30 seconds.